# Drop the last character of string, if the last character is s

Tags: sql-server-2014

Working through an odd issue that the moment and trying to find a solution. If we have a string variable (@string) how might we drop the last character of the string, ONLY if the last character is an s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems a bit odd issue but here's how to do it.

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(10)
SET @string = 'Tests'

SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN RIGHT(@string,1) IN ('s','S') THEN SUBSTRING(@string,1,LEN(@string)-1)
    ELSE @string
  END AS string
```

Comment: `LEFT` instead of `SUBSTRING` is slightly shorter